# Changing CSS before pageload with Greasemonkey

Tags: css, greasemonkey

I need to hide an element on the page using greasemonkey *before* it loads (so that it's never visible).

At the moment I'm `@require`ing jQuery 1.3.2 which I'm reasonably familiar with, but I'm unsure how it interacts with greasemonkey so I don't know how to pull this off!

Many thanks,

JP

Comment: Good spot skaffman, it does look like this is a CSS question - seeing as I can't interact with the DOM before it's loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greasemonkey cannot do this for you, this is one of the scenarios where you should use a [userstyle](http://userstyles.org/help/userstyles).

Many people who write userscripts also create a userstyle that can go along with the userscript, which will change CSS styles before the page loads, to improve the user experience. Usually they upload their userscript to [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org) and add a link in the description to the associated userstyle on [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org).